# Python: Extract JSON keys

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON string:

```
jsonString = {'result': {'animals': {'Dogs': True, 'Cats': True}}
```

So in Python I know I can do:

```
animals= jsonString['result']['animals']
```

To get the value of 'Dogs' or 'Cats'. And:

```
animals= jsonString['result']['animals']['Dogs']
```

To get the value of 'Dogs' or 'Cats'.

However, when I try `print (jsonString['result']['animals'])` I get:

```
{'Dogs': True, 'Cats': True}
```

Question

How do I get the all the animals, without values, dynamically?

Thanks.

Comment: What result are you looking for?  something like `['Dogs', 'Cats']`?

Comment: `jsonString['result']['cats'].keys()`?

Comment: you are actually using a `dict` and this has nothing to do with json, and I think you want `.keys()` to get the keys of the dict, however the print statement you provided is not a valid python command

Comment: Well, I should have mentioned .keys(). This returns the "dict_keys(['Dogs','Cats'])" output. I am looking for something like: ['Dogs', 'Cats']

Comment: It's quite confusing you are mixing "cats" and "Cats" at different levels. It would be better to format your questions like "animals: [Dogs, Cats]"

Comment: This is the answer `list(jsonString["result"]["cats"].keys())` but accept Tadhg McDonald-Jensen's answer; it's more informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off when the data is loaded from json it creates a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) object, so all the methods described in the documentation are usable including [`keys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys):

```
print(jsonString['result']['cats'].keys())
```

you can see a list of all the possible methods with `dir(dict)` or `dir(jsonString)` and get `help` on any of them with the built in function:

```
>>> help(dict.keys)
Help on method_descriptor:

keys(...)
    D.keys() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's keys
```